# Server/Client Changing Address While Connected

Tags: c#, server, client

What I'am Asking Is : 
For Example We have a Client and a Server already in touch ( connected ) 
The Client Connected on the address and the port of the Server and the Server Address Is on a variable linked with database (Dynamic) For example No-ip
Can i change the address of the Client Redirect it To an other address While (Connected) And keep the first connection ON and connect it to Another Server (2 Conenctions at the same time ) But The Seconde Connection Was incoming

I don't Know if you would Get the question Right But Lets say the Client Was Conencting From the Begining to 2 Servers But the seconde one was inactif till i changed it address in My Database !
and thank you !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guessed the gist of your question... I assume you are talking about berkley sockets connections.
Yes, you can have your client to have 2 connections, one for active, one for passive server (active/passive schema). Alternatively, you can have 2 connections to 2 active servers (active/active schema).

In the first scenario, if IP address of server 1 is changed, connection will be dropped and your passive server becomes active and can communicate to client the new IP address of the server 1.

In the second scenario, active server 2 can communicate to the client the new IP address of server 1.

To do that you need to implement server method to return IP addresses of both servers upon client request. The client should request IP addresses over remaining connection if one of connections is dropped.

Comment: Hi ! , Thank you For your Answer , if the Connection 1 to the Server 1 Is dropped (Changing Adress of the Server ) Will reconnect to the new server ?

Comment: And the Server Can have 2 Adress ?

Comment: No, Client code should detect connection failure, request new IP address table from remaining connection and then create new connection using new IP address. You will have to code that.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks Again ! , Then I can create an event contains (if the Conenction is dropped Create a new Connection Using This adress [Adress] ? ? would this work ?

Comment: Something like this. Remember to request new IP address. Client is not aware of new address, it has to request it.

Comment: I Basically understand that , to request new IP adress , can i ask how can i do that generally ?

Comment: Actual implementation depends on the coding language and library used.

Comment: I'am Using C# Language System.Net

Comment: Then use WCF, it is way simpler than coding sockets.

Comment: Thought 'bout that ! , Thank You So Much !